# IsolatedStorageException on first cache access

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7.1

I am having an issue where I am getting an IsolatedStorageException ('Operation not permitted on IsolatedFileStorageStream') every first time I run an app.  Consequent times of running the app, it works just fine.  I have tried every method I could find of open files for writing, including

```
using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, iso))
{
}

using(var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using(IsolatedStorageFileStream file = iso.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
}
```

and other various overloads of those methods.  Nothing I do has worked, and I have followed the steps on every other post in Stack Overflow and every blog post I could find.  When I look at the output, every time it throws the following exceptions:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Does anyone have any other ideas as to why it's exploding?  I'm using WP7 7.1 RTM tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that if you have a file name with funny characters in it, you will get an exception, but then for some reason it accepts the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This is were i learned how to write to isolated storage on the WP7,

[Using Isolated Storage on Windows Phone 7](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/09/03/Using-Isolated-Storage-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
if (!myStore.DirectoryExists(directory))
{    

    myStore.CreateDirectory(directory);                 
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 

    {                         
         using (var isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(directory+"//yourfilename.jpg"))  

       {                             
         //her what do you want....
      }  

   }  

}
```